# Can templated field reference template parameters be passed as the first template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following method in a `template <class Base> class foo {}`:

```
template <
    typename V,
    template <class, class> class Map,
    Map<std::string, V> Base::*Field,
    std::size_t Len
>
constexpr const foo<Base> s(char const (&section_name)[Len]) const {
    #pragma unused(section_name)
    return *this;
}
```

My goal is to be able to call it simply with:

```
struct my_struct {
    std::map<std::string, int> section;
    constexpr auto bar = foo<my_struct>()
        .s<&my_struct::section>("hi");
};
```

Is this possible, perhaps via specialization? I can't wrap my head around how to get this to even compile, as currently I can't pass the pointer-to-member since the templated Map type comes first in the declaration, which gives the me the following on clang:

> note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Map'

And I can't seem to get the magical incantations of specialization to work, either:

```
template <auto FieldType, std::size_t Len>
constexpr const foo<Base> s(char const (&section_name)[Len]) const;

template <
    template <class, class> class Map,
    typename SecType,
    Map<std::string, SecType> Base::*Field,
    std::size_t Len
>
constexpr const foo<Base> s<Field, Len>(char const (&section_name)[Len]) const {

}
```

which gives

> error: function template partial specialization is not allowed

Is what I'm after even possible? Worth mentioning c++14 and onward is OK.

Comment: Sorry for the word jumble of the title; not entirely sure of all the terminology being used here so I did my best.

Comment: Are you looking for `template <auto MemberPointer, std::size_t Len>`? (This requires C++17.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hello again :) I was trying to avoid it, but if that's the only way then I can accept that. However, I'd still like to enforce that the map type has a `std::string` key. Is that done via specialization?

Comment: Yup, you can either specialize the template, or use a `static_assert` (if you figure out how to write the condition properly).

Comment: Alright, fair enough. Can you post an answer so I can give you those sweet, sweet fake internet points?

Comment: I'm too sleepy to write one, so I'll leave this to you. :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, can't figure out the specialization either. I feel useless this evening lol. Edited the question with what I tried, but it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

For a pre-C++17 solution you can put the member pointer into an `std::integral_constant`. To make sure the key type of your map is a `std::string`, use type deduction to get the member type from the pointer and compare its key type with `std::string`:

```c++
template<class T, class C>
T get_member_type(T C::*);

template<class Base>
struct foo{
  template<class I, std::size_t Len>
  constexpr const foo<Base> s(I, char const (&section_name)[Len]) const {
    using M=decltype(get_member_type(I::value));
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename M::key_type, std::string>{});
    return *this;
  }
};

#define CONST(e) std::integral_constant<decltype(e), e>

struct my_struct {
  std::map<std::string, int> section;
  constexpr static auto bar = foo<my_struct>().s(CONST(&my_struct::section){}, "hi");
};
```

The error you get in your edit is due to the fact that you cannot partially specialize function templates. Fortunately you can extend the code in my answer above so that you can overload based on the key type with tag dispatching:

```c++
template<class Base>
struct foo{
  template<class M>
  using get_key_type = typename M::key_type;
  template<class I>
  using get_member_type = decltype(::get_member_type(I::value));

  template<class I, std::size_t Len>
  constexpr auto s(I, char const (&section_name)[Len]) const {
    return s(I{}, section_name, 
      std::is_same<get_key_type<get_member_type<I>>, std::string>{}
    );
  }
private:
  template<class I, std::size_t Len>
  constexpr const auto s(I, char const (&section_name)[Len], std::false_type) const {
    return *this;
  }

  template<class I, std::size_t Len>
  constexpr const auto s(I, char const (&section_name)[Len], std::true_type) const {
    return *this;
  }
};
```